# list the indices of the lowest and highest grades entered

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have the user input test grades UNTIL user enters a negative number. The program will:

• have a function without parameters that returns a list of the grades

• have a function with a list parameter that returns the index of the lowest grade

• have a function with a list parameter that returns the index of the highest grade

• list the number of grades entered,

• list the lowest and highest grades entered,

• list the indices of the lowest and highest grades entered,

• For example:

```
Enter score 1: 88.8

Enter score 2: 50

Enter score 3: 100

Enter score 4: 100

Enter score 5: -1

Number of valid grades: 4

The lowest grade: 50

The highest grade: 100

The lowest grade index: 1 (notice the index used is not for the negative number)

The highest grade index: 2 (notice the index used is for the first ”100” entered) Grades:

Grades: [88.8, 50, 100, 100]
```

Source code:

```
def getGrades():
    grades = []
    while True:
        grade = float(input("enter a test grade (enter a negative number to quit):"))
    if grade < 0 :
        break
    grades.append(grade)
return grades

def getLowestIndex(grades):
   return grades.index(min(grades))

def getHighestIndex(grades):
    return grades.index(min(grades))

def main():
    grades = getGrades()

if grades < 0:
    print("Invalid, no grades entered.")

else:
    num_grades = len(grades)
    lowest_grade = min(grades)
    highest_grade = max(grades)
    lowest_index = getLowestIndex(grades)
    highest_index = getHighestIndex(grades)


    print(f"\nNumber of valid grades: {num_grades}")
    print(f"Lowest grade : {lowest_grade})
    print(f"Highest grade: {highest_grade} (at index {highest_index})")
    print(f"Lowest grade index : {lowest_index} ")
    print(f"Highest grade index: {highest_index} ")
    print(" Grades: {grades}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind updating your question with the desired result? Keep in mind that array indexing starts from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask].

Comment: You have a return outside a function. That will cause an error

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to try reading and understanding the default error messages.
This is the list of problems in your code:

1. In the function getGrades(), Wrong indentation of if statement
2. In the function getGrades(), add else statement.
3. In the function getGrades(), wrong indentation of return statement
4. In the function  getHighestIndex, typed min instead of max
5. declare grades as a variable, but not inside the function main.
6. It should be 'if len(grades) < 0:' and not 'if grades < 0:'
7. double quote is missing in the second print statement
8. Unwanted braces in the third print statement
9. f is missing in the sixth print statement

This is how the code is supposed to be:

```
def getGrades():
    grades = []
    while True:
        grade = float(input("enter a test grade (enter a negative number to quit):"))
        if grade < 0 :
            break
        else:
            grades.append(grade)
    return grades

def getLowestIndex(grades):
   return grades.index(min(grades))

def getHighestIndex(grades):
    return grades.index(max(grades))


grades = getGrades()

if len(grades) < 0:
    print("Invalid, no grades entered.")

else:
    num_grades = len(grades)
    lowest_grade = min(grades)
    highest_grade = max(grades)
    lowest_index = getLowestIndex(grades)
    highest_index = getHighestIndex(grades)


    print(f"\nNumber of valid grades: {num_grades}")
    print(f"Lowest grade : {lowest_grade}")
    print(f"Highest grade: {highest_grade} at index {highest_index}")
    print(f"Lowest grade index : {lowest_index} ")
    print(f"Highest grade index: {highest_index} ")
    print(f"Grades: {grades}")
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here are some example implementations.

> *"... have a function without parameters that returns a list of the grades ..."*

```py
def grades():
    g = []
    i, x = 0, 0
    while x >= 0:
        if (x := int(input(f'grade {(i := i + 1)}:  '))) >= 0:
            g.append(x)
    return g
```

> *"... have a function with a list parameter that returns the index of the lowest grade ..."*

```py
def lowest(g: list):
    return g.index(min(g))
```

> *"... have a function with a list parameter that returns the index of the highest grade ..."*

```py
def highest(g: list):
    return g.index(max(g))
```

> *"... list the number of grades entered ..."*

Presuming there is a *list* of grades; call it *g*.

```py
print(len(g))
```

> *"... list the lowest and highest grades entered ..."*

```py
print(min(g), max(g))
```

> *"... list the indices of the lowest and highest grades entered ..."*

```py
print(lowest(g), highest(g))
```

Here is an example output.

```
grade 1:  100
grade 2:  90
grade 3:  80
grade 4:  70
grade 5:  -1
4
70 100
3 0
```